Can CloudRun autoscale against resource utilization of Java Spring process pulling event streams from a GCP Pub Sub topic?
I cannot find definitive information on whether or not Cloud Run can autoscale against cpu or memory utilization when running a Java Spring process e.g. Spring Cloud GCP which is consuming from a GCP Pub Sub topic via a pull subscription.
The Google documentation recommends using push subscriptions when using CloudRun which would enable cloud run to scale against the incomming http requests. (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling)
However my use case requires events to be pulled from a topic
I have also read that CloudRun is not able to scale effectively against background processes which are e.g. async. (https://blog.thecloudside.com/maximizing-reliability-cloud-run-autoscaling-and-cloud-tasks-in-action-b02aabc02ffb)
I am trying to figure out whether using Cloud Run is a good use case for running a Spring process pulling events off a GCP Pub Sub topic with a medium to high load/ throughput. Or whether I should look at alternative solutions such as GKE which would also allow utilization of Topic metrics such as Topic depth
Reading articles online to confirm behaviour, currently trying out a PoC to confirm behaviour

Do you want to push or to pull from PubSUb? It's not clear in your question. For more details about scaling, refer to the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling

I want to pull from pub sub

Pull from PubSub is not a good idea with Cloud Run (right now, something is cooking, but won't be ready soon). Because you have  limited period of time (timeout, 60 minutes for Cloud Run Services, 7 days for Cloud Run jobs), pulling is limited in the time. You could imagine scheduling every week a new Cloud Run job, but it's inefficient, and not really scalable. If you want to use Cloud Run and PubSub, push subscription is the key to scale automatically and not to worry about the timeout
